# What are the coercion rules in dplyr 0.5.0?

Tags: r, dplyr

I was reading the helpfile for `dplyr::bind` when I noticed this statement:

> combine() acts like c() or unlist() but uses consistent dplyr coercion rules.

What does it mean by 'consistent dplyr coercion rules'?

Comment: First Google result for `dplyr coercion rules` - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/two-table.html See "coercion rules" heading - might be useful as a start

Comment: thanks! don't know how I failed to see that.